# Excel conditional formatting matching text in other cell that may include other text as well

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2016

I am trying to do some conditionally formatting for a sports draft I'm currently taking part in.

I've included a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iyn4.png) of my 2 sheets I'm working off of. The top sheet is the `draft pool` and the bottom sheet is `drafted`.

What I'm trying to do is a conditional formatting that highlights players in the `draft pool` sheet that appear on the `drafted` sheet. The issue I run into is how the site we are using to draft provides this information.

In column E on `drafted` the cell includes the players position before their name and I'm unsure of a formula that would apply conditional formatting if a players name in column B on `draft pool` is in column E on `drafted` since it includes extra text before the actual name I'm trying to match.

Comment: I would edit column E on drafted to remove the position. You could duplicate that column, then look for the first space and keep everything to the right of it. Other ways to do it, too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FIND()` or `SEARCH()` on the range covered by the potential number of "drafted" entries. (At most, that's what, seven rounds, 32 teams, maybe a potential extra or two for some weird reason, so not a huge range to not use for anything else.)

If either locates the name in any of the cells in the range, a positive value will be returned. If they do not, errors are returned which will dominate and return an overall error. So use `IFERROR()`, with the if so return being "0", and you are covered. `SUM()` the return results and if that value is NOT 0 (i.e.:  <>0 ), then the name given IS present. Note that the input can be a full name, so all the "Johnson" folks can be differentiated.

A formula for this could look like:

```
=IF(SUM(IFERROR(FIND("Trachtenberg",A1:A3),0))<>0,"Drafted Already","Available")
```

though this would be cell-side, like testing for some other reason. For use in Conditional Formatting, you need to put it into a TRUE-FALSE form rather than the strict IF-THEN-ELSE form above:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(FIND("Trachtenberg",A1:A3),0))<>0
```

yields a TRUE-FALSE situation giving a TRUE if present in the already drafted range. Since it is TRUE, the formatting will be activated, as desired. (Gotta admit, that seems backward to me, offhand, 'cause I'd expect everyone available to be marked, not the opposite, but I am not examining the overall logic, just saying marking the goners seems odd. The other natural thought is to format them so they go away, blanks show, and perhaps you have that in mind. Sorry, just seemed strange.)

If you have `SPILL` functionality, it works as is in the IF-THEN-ELSE version. Without? Use {CSE} on it. No good way to use {CSE} inside Conditional Formatting (or Named Ranges for that matter). However, you can set up a column of formulas using the TRUE-FALSE version that does the draft pool names one by one, resulting in a series of TRUE or FALSE values. The CF TRUE-FALSE formula could then be something like:

```
=SUM(IFERROR(A1:A230,0))<>0
```

which is analogous to how one gets past functions that cannot work on closed spreadsheets. I see your Excel-2016 tag so maybe this would matter to you. To hide the magic, if important to your application, you could put a Named Range in the middle with it having the `IFERROR(A1:A230,0)` part so you might have something visible to the world like:

```
=SUM(DraftedAlready)<>0
```